# How to using loop with oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is a query in a procedure where I pull the data and write it to the table:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTR(sl.TASK_JOB_ID,1,12) AS schedule_id,
    null AS schedule_seq,
    null AS schedule_subseq,
    BULK COLLECT
INTO 
    v_schedule_detail_table 
FROM 
    sch_line sl,
    SCH_INPUT_MATERIAL sim ,
    SCH_INPUT_PIECE sip,
    SCH_PIECES_RELATION spr,
    SCH_CUT sc
WHERE 
    sl.TASK_JOB_ID = v_schedule_table(i).schedule_id  
    AND sl.SCH_LINE_NUM_ID = sim.SCH_LINE_NUM_ID 
    AND sim.INPUT_MAT_NUM_ID = sip.INPUT_MAT_NUM_ID
    AND sip.INPUT_PIECE_NUM_ID = spr.INPUT_PIECE_NUM_ID 
    AND spr.SCHC_CUT_NUM_ID = sc.SCHC_CUT_NUM_ID;
```

When this code gets the data in sch_cut table , I want to fills schedule seq and schedule_subseq as in the example below.

For an example schedule id value, the following output of the sch_cut table appears.

[image: SCH_CUT]

According to this table without taking the value of 0 in piece grouping ;

- If to_cut_trans_flag = Y, then that values increment to schedule_seq
- If to_cut_long_flag = Y, then that values increment to schedule_subseq

and the algorithm will be as follows

[image]

Finally the output I want to see for this example should be filled like this

[image]

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: mysql or oracle?

Comment: that is oracle query